# How can I get all the handles of the all dll files?

Tags: c#, dll

I can't get handles for all listed dll files of a given program.
I want to get all the handles of the listed dll files.
The most important would be the WebKit.dll but its handles is zero.

Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
        Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("program");
        Process process1 = process[0];

        ProcessModuleCollection modules = process1.Modules;
        ProcessModule dllBaseAdress = null;
        foreach (ProcessModule m in modules)
        {
            // LIST ALL DLL OF THE PROGRAM PROCESS:
            if (m.ModuleName != "WebKit.dll1")
            {

                dllBaseAdress = m;
                string DLL_file_name = m.ModuleName;                    
                IntPtr DLL_file = GetModuleHandle(DLL_file_name);
                Console.WriteLine("GetModuleHandle: " + DLL_file.ToInt32() + ", DLL Name: " + m.ModuleName + "\n");
                //break;
            }
        }
        IntPtr WebKit_dll = GetModuleHandle("WebKit.dll");
        Console.WriteLine("GetModuleHandle: " + WebKit_dll.ToInt32());

        IntPtr dllPtr = dllBaseAdress.BaseAddress;
        Console.WriteLine("\nDLL BaseAdress.BaseAddress: " + dllPtr + " ");
```

Comment: `"WebKit.dll1'` doesn't look right.

Comment: Its handle is zero and I don't know why.
I think it must be not zero.

Comment: Be more specific.  You have several handles there.  Which one, specifically, is zero?  And what do you expect it to be?  and what is `"program"`?

Comment: And what is `GetModuleHandle()`?  Is it the Win32 function or the `System.RuntimeTypeHandle` method?

Comment: More specifically, Sam Axe (who is obviously a Burn Notice fan, and I approve), is asking why you have ".dll1" (with a one in it), not ".dll".

Comment: The "program" is an exe filename, a flash game.
The most handles of dll files in this case is zero.
I need for this to a pointer steps to get to the final address.
The WebKit.dll works only with the pointers what I need for.

Comment: This solution is fundamentally flawed.  GetModuleHandle will only give you handles for the currently executing process, not some arbitrary process.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a complete answer, but is a starting point.  If I have time I will come back to add more detail later.

You would like to have a program which enumerates all the DLL modules loaded by some arbitrary second process.  GetModuleHandle cannot be used for this purpose as it only retrieves handles for the currently executing process:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
>   **GetModuleHandle function**
>   Retrieves a module handle for the specified
>   module. The module must have been loaded by the calling process.

In order to accomplish this from C# it appears that P/Invoke on Win32 API function NtQuerySystemInformation is needed.

I found this reference which appears to show all the relevant functions and structures that are required: http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic18892.html